# Coordinates of rounded rectangle

Tags: kotlin, coordinates, rectangles, ellipse

I'm drawing a rounded rectangle with significant radius (on a Canvas in kotlin).
To do that, I define the coordinates of the drawn rectangle and provide the *x* and *y* radius for the corners.

Now I want to draw other stuff all around the rounded rectangle.

What is the equations to find my *(x,y)* point coordinates given an angle on this rounded rectangle?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented my own algorithm:

```
fun roundedRectanglePerimeterPoints(positions: Int, rect: RectF, xRadius: Float, yRadius: Float): List<PointF> {

    val segments = listOf(
        Line(rect.centerX(), rect.bottom, rect.left + xRadius, rect.bottom),
        EllipseQuarter(rect.left + xRadius, rect.bottom - yRadius, xRadius, yRadius, EllipseQuarter.Direction.SOUTH_WEST),
        Line(rect.left, rect.bottom - yRadius, rect.left, rect.top + yRadius),
        EllipseQuarter(rect.left + xRadius, rect.top + yRadius, xRadius, yRadius, EllipseQuarter.Direction.NORTH_WEST),
        Line(rect.left + xRadius, rect.top, rect.right - xRadius, rect.top),
        EllipseQuarter(rect.right - xRadius, rect.top + yRadius, xRadius, yRadius, EllipseQuarter.Direction.NORTH_EAST),
        Line(rect.right, rect.top + yRadius, rect.right, rect.bottom - yRadius),
        EllipseQuarter(rect.right - xRadius, rect.bottom - yRadius, xRadius, yRadius, EllipseQuarter.Direction.SOUTH_EAST),
        Line(rect.right - xRadius, rect.bottom, rect.centerX(), rect.bottom)
    )

    val perimeter = segments.sumByDouble { it.length.toDouble() }
    val distancePerPlayer = perimeter / positions

    val playerPoints = mutableListOf<PointF>()
    for (i in 0 until positions) {
        var distanceFromOrigin = i * distancePerPlayer.toFloat()
        var pathIndex = 0

        while (distanceFromOrigin > segments[pathIndex].length) {
            distanceFromOrigin -= segments[pathIndex].length
            pathIndex++
        }

        val p = segments[pathIndex].pointForDistance(distanceFromOrigin)
        playerPoints.add(p)
    }

    return playerPoints
}
```